# Uploadind pdf in my database available on to my server

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I was trying on to my localhost and it was working fine only pdf's were goinf 
   into my health folder. But how can I upload my pdf files or all files types 
   on to database which is on my server?

```
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
    $folder_path = 'health/';

   echo $filename = basename($_FILES['healthfile']['name']);
   $newname = $folder_path . $filename;

   $FileType = pathinfo($newname,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

   if($FileType == "pdf")
   {
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['healthfile']['tmp_name'], $newname))
   {

   $filesql = "INSERT INTO user(pdf) VALUES('$filename') WHERE id='$id'";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $filesql);
    if (isset($query))
    {
     echo 'File Uploaded';
    } else
    {
    echo 'Something went Wrong';
    }
    }
    else
    {

    echo "<p>Upload Failed.</p>";
    }


    }
    else
    {
    echo "<p>Class notes must be uploaded in PDF format.</p>";
    }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: remove if($FileType == "pdf")  condition.

Comment: Why should I remove this I will write OR clause for uploading all files @Star_Man .

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fname=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $ftype=$_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fsize=$_FILES['file']['size'];
    $ferror=$_FILES['file']['error'];
    $ftmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $link=@fopen($ftmp,"r");
    $file=@fread($link,$fsize);
    $pdf=addslashes($file);
    if($ftype=="pdf")
    {
        $query="insert into user values('$pdf','$ftype')";
        $rs=@mysql_query($query);
        if($rs)
        {
            echo "Upload Successful";
        }
        else
        {
            $tmp=mysql_error();
            echo $tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

You must add code for connecting database.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility  of `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['healthfile']['tmp_name'], $newname))` always returning false due to file write permissions issues on the folder intended to contain the uploaded files.